Nomenclature, references and bibliography are not displayed after Latex compilation in arXiv
I have written a paper with Latex (overleaf) and submitted it to a journal. I would also like to publish a preprint in arXiv. Unfortunately, arXiv does not seem to allow pdf uploads but just wants the tex files. The big problem when uploading my latex files is that the created pdf file from arXiv does not display the nomenclature, the references are all a ? and there is no bibliography section. So apparently arXiv is using another compiler than in overleaf. So my question is ifI can change the latex compiling in arXiv (I have to admit that I have no experience with something like this).
Here is the upper part of the output of the arXiv latex compiler (the entire output is too long for StackExchange):
Highlighted AutoTeX Log:

[verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2023 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: <refs.bib> is of type 'BiBTeX'.
[verbose]: <main.tex> is of type 'LATEX2e'.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Processing file 'main.tex'
[verbose]: arXiv Warning: user included plain hyperref directive.
[verbose]: arXiv Warning: user included plain hyperref directive.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running latex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5729616/ && latex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=latex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-05-05>
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls
Document Class: elsarticle 2020/11/20, 3.3: Elsevier Ltd
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifvtex.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fleqn.clo))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/txfonts.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/physics/physics.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hdvips.def
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pdfmark.def
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/csquotes/csquotes.cfg))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acro/acro.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty))
(./sections/00_acro.tex) (/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.ltd.tex))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/comment/comment.sty
Excluding comment 'comment')
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/subcaption.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption-elsarticle.sto))))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/framed/framed.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty

Package multicol Warning: May not work with the twocolumn option on input line
143.

) (/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/nomencl/nomencl.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/tocbasic.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrbase.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlfile-hook.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrlogo.sty))))))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xurl/xurl.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/todonotes/todonotes.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code
.tex)) (/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvips.def
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-postscript.
def)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)

(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.c
ode.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex
)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmet
ics.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.
tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.cod
e.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.t
ex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty
)) (/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code
.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arytopaths.code.tex)))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibr
arypositioning.code.tex) (/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty))
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecell/makecell.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/afterpage.sty)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/ot1txr.fd)
No file main.aux.
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/omltxmi.fd)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/omstxsy.fd)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/omxtxex.fd)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/utxexa.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips

Package siunitx Warning: Detected the "physics" package:
(siunitx) omitting definition of \qty.
(siunitx)
(siunitx) If you want to use \qty with the siunitx definition,
(siunitx) add
(siunitx)
(siunitx) \AtBeginDocument{\RenewCommandCopy\qty\SI}
(siunitx)
(siunitx) to your preamble.


(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations-basic-dictionary-
english.trsl)

Package hyperref Warning: Rerun to get /PageLabels entry.


Package todonotes Warning: The length marginparwidth is less than 2cm and will
most likely cause issues with the appearance of inserted todonotes. The issue c
an be solved by adding a line like \setlength {\marginparwidth }{2cm} prior to
loading the todonotes package. on input line 66.

(./sections/00_abstract.tex) Excluding 'comment' comment.
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/utxmia.fd)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/utxsyc.fd)
(./sections/00_nomecl.tex
No file main.nls.
) (./sections/01_intro.tex

Package natbib Warning: Citation `PATTEEUW2015306' on page 1 undefined on input
line 5.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `ANTONOPOULOS2020109899' on page 1 undefined o
n input line 7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dinh2022_2' on page 1 undefined on input line
7.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Cao2020' on page 1 undefined on input line 7.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dinh2022_2' on page 1 undefined on input line
10.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dinh2022_2' on page 1 undefined on input line
12.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Pan2021' on page 1 undefined on input line 12
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec_related_work_and_contribution' on page 1 undefine
d on input line 14.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:Optimization problem of the building' on page 1 u
ndefined on input line 14.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:Imitation learning for building control' on page
1 undefined on input line 14.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:Results' on page 1 undefined on input line 14.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:Conclusion' on page 1 undefined on input line 14.


) (./sections/02_related_work.tex

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Javed2017' on page 1 undefined on input line
18.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Kim2020' on page 1 undefined on input line 20
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `DEY2023' on page 1 undefined on input line 22
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Zou2020' on page 1 undefined on input line 24
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dinh2022_2' on page 1 undefined on input line
27.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Zhang2020' on page 1 undefined on input line
30.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dinh2022' on page 1 undefined on input line 3
2.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Ahmed2016' on page 1 undefined on input line
35.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Gao2022' on page 1 undefined on input line 37
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `L\xc3\xb3pez2019' on page 1 undefined on input line
39.


Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active [1]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `tab_literature' on page 2 undefined on input line 48.



Package natbib Warning: Citation `Javed2017' on page 2 undefined on input line
48.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Kim2020' on page 2 undefined on input line 48
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `DEY2023' on page 2 undefined on input line 48
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Zou2020' on page 2 undefined on input line 48
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dinh2022_2' on page 2 undefined on input line
48.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Javed2017' on page 2 undefined on input line
48.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Kim2020' on page 2 undefined on input line 48
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `DEY2023' on page 2 undefined on input line 48
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Zou2020' on page 2 undefined on input line 48
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dinh2022_2' on page 2 undefined on input line
48.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Zhang2020' on page 2 undefined on input line
50.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dinh2022' on page 2 undefined on input line 5
0.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Ahmed2016' on page 2 undefined on input line
50.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Gao2022' on page 2 undefined on input line 50
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `L\xc3\xb3pez2019' on page 2 undefined on input line
50.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Zhang2020' on page 2 undefined on input line
50.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dinh2022' on page 2 undefined on input line 5
0.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Ahmed2016' on page 2 undefined on input line
50.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Gao2022' on page 2 undefined on input line 50
.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `L\xc3\xb3pez2019' on page 2 undefined on input line
50.

(/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/txfonts/ts1txr.fd))
(./sections/03_optimization_problem_for_the_building.tex

LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:objective_function' on page 2 undefined on input l
ine 5.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:temperature_balance' on page 2 undefined on input
line 33.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:non_negativity' on page 2 undefined on input line
33.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:temperature_balance' on page 2 undefined on input
line 33.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:temperature_difference_equation' on page 2 undefin
ed on input line 33.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `subsec:Scenarios_for_the_analysis' on page 2 undefine
d on input line 33.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:heating_energy_HP' on page 2 undefined on input li
ne 33.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `subsec:Scenarios_for_the_analysis' on page 2 undefine
d on input line 33.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:hp_switched_off_1' on page 2 undefined on input li
ne 33.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:hp_switched_off_5' on page 2 undefined on input li
ne 33.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:hp_min_mod_1' on page 2 undefined on input line 33
.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `eq:hp_min_mod_2' on page 2 undefined on input line 33
.

[2]) (./sections/04_immitation_learning_for_building_control.tex

Package natbib Warning: Citation `FRAHM2023' on page 3 undefined on input line
5.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Hussein2017' on page 3 undefined on input lin
e 5.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:Optimization problem of the building' on page 3 u
ndefined on input line 5.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:PSC_ML_Training' on page 3 undefined on input lin
e 7.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:Optimization problem of the building' on page 3 u
ndefined on input line 7.


! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in figures/PSC_ML_Training.png
(no BoundingBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...

l.16 ...4\textheight]{figures/PSC_ML_Training.png}

?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.16 ...4\textheight]{figures/PSC_ML_Training.png}

Output written on main.dvi (2 pages, 32112 bytes).
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: latex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.spl' (1720889050 >= 1720889049)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.aux' (1720889050 >= 1720889049)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.out' (1720889050 >= 1720889049)
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.nlo' (1720889050 >= 1720889049)
[verbose]: removing leftover dvi file 'main.dvi'
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running hpdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2023/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/5729616/ && pdflatex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

When using Overleaft the created pdf looks fine.

you are producing dvi and that can handle png. You can ensure pdflatex processing by setting the flag \pdfoutput=1 within the first 5 lines of the preamble of the main. See https://info.arxiv.org/help/submit_tex.html (arxiv is in the process to drop their autotex system, so hopefully that will get easier in future.)

Unlike Overleaf, arXiv.org does not run bibtex, makeindex and the like for submitted documents. To get the bibliography to appear, you need to submit the .bbl file. Similarly the relevant file for the nomenclature etc must be submitted.  See https://info.arxiv.org/help/submit_tex.html for details.

Thanks a lot Ulrike and John for your comments. I added what Ulrike suggested \pdfoutput=1 in the third line of main main.tex file. Further, I separately uploaded the .bib file with the name main.bib. Actually nothing changed on the resulting pdf. There is still no nomenclature and bibliography section and the citation are all "?"

It's the .bbl file, not the .bib file you need to upload. The .bib file would only be relevant if arXiv.org ran bibtex, which it doesn't.  To find the .bbl file (and the .nls file for the nomenclature) after a compilation on Overleaf, go to the "Logs and output files" item and then click on "Other logs and files".

@JohnCollins: Thanks John for your comment. I really appreciate it. Now it displays the bibliography and the nomenclature. Is there anything else I need to take care of?

Probably nothing else needs to be done. Normally, I'd look at the listing of the output from the compilation from arXiv.org to see if there are any errors or important warnings, and I'd also view the pdf file and scan for any problems there.

@JohnCollins: Thanks a lot for your help John. I really appreciate it.
